# DatePicker not visible using a ModelForm - crispy

Tags: python, django

I have a modelForm base on my model Randomization 
I'm using crispy in my template (Randomzation_edit.html) and DateInput() in my form (RandomizationForm)

unformtunatly, I did not have DatePicker in my edit form

What is the problem?

forms.py

```py
from django import forms
from .models import Randomisation

class RandomisationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    TYPES = [
        (1, 'On-line'),
        (2, 'Telephon'),
    ]
    ran_num = forms.CharField(label="Patient code",disabled=True)
    ran_dat = forms.DateInput()
    ran_pro = forms.ChoiceField(label="Type", widget=forms.Select, choices=TYPES)

    class Meta:
        model = Randomisation
        fields = ('ran_num','ran_dat','ran_inv','ran_pro','ran_pro_per','ran_crf_inc','ran_tbc','ran_crf_eli','ran_cri','ran_sta','ran_vih','ran_bra','ran_med',)
```

models.py

```py
class Randomisation(models.Model):

    ran_ide = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ran_num = models.CharField("Patient code", max_length=10, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    ran_dat = models.DateTimeField("Today's date", null=True, blank=True)
    ran_inv = models.CharField("Investigator", max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    ran_pro = models.IntegerField("Procedure used to randomized", null=True, blank=True)
    ran_pro_per = models.IntegerField("if telephone, name of the person reached on the phone", null=True, blank=True)
    ran_crf_inc = models.IntegerField("Was the CRF inclusion 2 Eligibility fulfilled?", null=True, blank=True)
    ran_tbc = models.IntegerField("Is TB diagnosis possible, probable or definite?", null=True, blank=True)
    ran_crf_eli = models.IntegerField("Was the CRF Inclusion 2 Eligibility fulffiled?", null=True, blank=True)
    ran_cri = models.IntegerField("Is the conclusion All criteria fulfilled for randomisation", null=True, blank=True)
    ran_sta = models.IntegerField("British Medical Council Staging (worst stage reported between first symptoms and now)", null=True, blank=True)
    ran_vih = models.IntegerField("HIV/AIDS status", null=True, blank=True)
    ran_bra = models.IntegerField("TB treatment assigned", null=True, blank=True)
    ran_med = models.IntegerField("Batch number", null=True, blank=True)
    ran_log_dat = models.DateTimeField("Date", null=True, blank=True)
    ran_log = models.CharField("Name of the person who performs randomisation on site", max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:

        db_table = 'crf_ran'
        verbose_name_plural = 'randomized'
        ordering = ['ran_num']

    def __str__(self):

        return f"{self.ran_ide}"
```

Randomization_edit.html

```py
{% extends 'layouts/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %}Index | Intense TBM{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<div class='container'>

<h1>Randomization form</h1>
</br>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form |crispy }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Randomize</button>
    </form>

</div>
</br></br></br></br>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here with `DateTimefield` is that the default input type of the field is `TextInput` due to which html does not recognize it as a `type=date` due to which no datepicker is shown in the form.
To change the input type to `datetime-local` or to `date` you have to make use of widgets in django which help in manipulation of the particular html input code.
Specifically for this condition you can try this ,see if it works:

**models.py**

```
class Randomisation(models.Model):

ran_ide = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
ran_num = models.CharField("Patient code", max_length=10, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
ran_dat = models.DateField("Today's date", null=True, blank=True)
ran_inv = models.CharField("Investigator", max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
ran_pro = models.IntegerField("Procedure used to randomized", null=True, blank=True)
ran_pro_per = models.IntegerField("if telephone, name of the person reached on the phone", null=True, blank=True)
ran_crf_inc = models.IntegerField("Was the CRF inclusion 2 Eligibility fulfilled?", null=True, blank=True)
ran_tbc = models.IntegerField("Is TB diagnosis possible, probable or definite?", null=True, blank=True)
ran_crf_eli = models.IntegerField("Was the CRF Inclusion 2 Eligibility fulffiled?", null=True, blank=True)
ran_cri = models.IntegerField("Is the conclusion All criteria fulfilled for randomisation", null=True, blank=True)
ran_sta = models.IntegerField("British Medical Council Staging (worst stage reported between first symptoms and now)", null=True, blank=True)
ran_vih = models.IntegerField("HIV/AIDS status", null=True, blank=True)
ran_bra = models.IntegerField("TB treatment assigned", null=True, blank=True)
ran_med = models.IntegerField("Batch number", null=True, blank=True)
ran_log_dat = models.DateField("Date", null=True, blank=True)
ran_log = models.CharField("Name of the person who performs randomisation on site", max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)

class Meta:

    db_table = 'crf_ran'
    verbose_name_plural = 'randomized'
    ordering = ['ran_num']

def __str__(self):

    return f"{self.ran_ide}"
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Randomisation

class RandomisationForm(forms.ModelForm):

TYPES = [
    (1, 'On-line'),
    (2, 'Telephon'),
]
ran_num = forms.CharField(label="Patient code",disabled=True)
ran_dat = forms.DateField(
          widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'type': 'date',
            'placeholder' : 'Date',
        }
    )
)
ran_pro = forms.ChoiceField(label="Type", widget=forms.Select, choices=TYPES)

class Meta:
    model = Randomisation
    fields = ('ran_num','ran_dat','ran_inv','ran_pro','ran_pro_per','ran_crf_inc','ran_tbc','ran_crf_eli','ran_cri','ran_sta','ran_vih','ran_bra','ran_med',)
```

and I suggest you to go and have a look at [Django Fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/) as well as at[Django widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/widgets/).
I hope this help.
Feel free to ask further doubts.

Comment: Thanks for replying ! it works ! I will look for a another widget that present a datepicker like bootstrap https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Okay!! Feel free to accept the answer if it works!!